# How can I check the radio button relative to a textbox?

Tags: jquery, textbox, focus, radio-button, checked

I'm trying to check in reference to the textbox selected, but when I change to other textbox  the first radio button stays checked! and I don't know how can I do to check the radio button according to every textbox.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="text" /> <input name="radio" type="radio" value="val1"/></p>
<p><input type="text" /><input name="radio" type="radio" value="val2"/></p>
<p><input type="text" /><input name="radio" type="radio" value="val3"/></p>
<p><input type="text" /><input name="radio" type="radio" value="val4"/></p>
<script>
$("input").focus(function () {
$('input:radio[name=radio]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you saying that if a user clicks inside a textbox, you want to mark the corresponding radio button as checked as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) for your specific layout. That is, considering the radio button immediately follows the input text.

```
$("input").focus(function() {
  $(this).next(":radio").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.6 it's recommended to use `.prop()` in this case.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jZsRt/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="text" /> <input name="radio" type="radio" value="val1"/></p>
<p><input type="text" /><input name="radio" type="radio" value="val2"/></p>
<p><input type="text" /><input name="radio" type="radio" value="val3"/></p>
<p><input type="text" /><input name="radio" type="radio" value="val4"/></p>
<script>
$(':text').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().children('input[type=radio]').attr('checked',true);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```